# Typescript : enforce generics to have some keys compulsory

Tags: typescript

I want the below function should only accept `data` object if there is `id` key in it. And then, want to access `id` from `data`.

```js
function someFuntion<T>(data : T){
const id = data['id']  //Error : Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature.
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a constraint to your generic type parameter:

```
function someFuntion<T extends { id: any}>(data : T){
    let id = data['id'] 
    id = data.id // also ok 
}
```

Comment: cool, thanks! 

I tried the same but was trying to set the same type to `data` as well, like `function someFuntion<T extends { id: any}>(data : T extends { id: any})` which was syntactically showing wrong.